# Can we make a build with unity ads without using or enabling unity services?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

While making build, i don't want to enable the unity services and don't want to link the organization in the services. Because when i enable unity services, my apk crashes on play. This particular happened when i use unity ads.

Comment: do you use admob Unity mediation too?

Comment: put the error you get when enabling Unity services.